# QML WebView does not want to start in Emulator

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml, ubuntu-emulator

When opening WebView in emulator I got this:

```
LaunchProcess: failed to execvp: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/oxide-qt/chrome-sandbox
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include the "webview" policy group in your apparmor profile.  At a minimum, the apparmor JSON file should be

```
{
    "policy_groups": [
        "networking",
        "webview"
    ],
    "policy_version": 1.2
}
```